# How does $\frac{y_1}{x_1-x_2}(x-x_2)+\frac{y_2}{x_2-x_1}(x-x_1)$ become $\frac{x_1y_2-x_2y_1}{x_1-x_2}+(\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2})x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working my way through pimbook.org and even though I feel like I'm OK in algebra, there is a section that I am having a hard time with.

On page 17 https://pimbook.org/pdf/pim_first_pages.pdf, it reads:

$$
f(x) = \frac{y_1}{x_1 - x_2}(x - x_2) + \frac{y_2}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1)
$$
"and simplify with typical algebra to get the form required by the definition:"
$$
f(x) = \frac{x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1}{x_1 - x_2} + (\frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_1 - x_2})x
$$

I am having difficulty with algebraically manipulating the first into the second. Could someone help with the steps that would make this more obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that :

$\dfrac{y_2}{x_2-x_1} (x-x_1) = \dfrac{-y_2}{x_1-x_2} (x-x_1)$

So

$f(x) = \dfrac{y_1}{x_1 - x_2}(x - x_2) + \dfrac{y_2}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1)$

$= \dfrac{y_1x -y_1x_2 - y_2x + y_2x_1}{x_1 - x_2} $

$= \dfrac{x(y_1 -y_2)}{x_1-x_2} + \dfrac{x_1y_2 - x_2y_1}{x_1-x_2}$

Comment: very helpful, thank you!